# Can a file read be combined in a list comprehension with list slicing?

Tags: python, twitter, list-comprehension, twython

The following code fragment is the core of a twitter bot using Twython. 
I would like to know if I can combine the file read into the list comprehension
as it seems rather convoluted to read a line in as a one-item list only to then
create another multi-item list from that.

I've checked around and found some examples where a whole file is read in using
readlines() for instance, but not one where slicing is involved too.

```
with open(tweet_datafile,'r') as smstweets:
    bigtweet = smstweets.readline().strip() 
    text_entire = [ bigtweet[i:i+140] for i in range(0,len(bigtweet),140) ]

for line in range(len(text_entire)):
    twitter.update_status(status=text_entire[line])
```

Notes:

Python 2.7, Linux. Python 3.5 is installed & available if needs be.

readline().strip() is used because I want to be able to read a file with lines 
of arbitrary length and remove any EOL and whitespace (the last item of the list 
could end up as spaces only; twitter will reject a status update of spaces, and I 
haven't yet written any error-handling for this).

I read only the first line of the input file and then later in the code write the file back out
minus that line. I decided this was the simplest solution for my limited skills as the bot won't run 24/7

I'm not a programmer, I've hacked this together using scraps of example code I 
found lying about on Stack Overflow and elsewhere.  I'm trying to use quite simple 
code and not rely on 3rd party libs apart from Twython. Generators and iterators
appear as sorcery to me.

Comment: I've retargeted the dupe to [split a generator/iterable every n items in python (splitEvery)](//stackoverflow.com/q/1915170), because it covers the case of a file better.

Comment: @MartijnPieters However, the dupe does not really answer the OP's question, which is not "how to split a sequence into fixed-length chunks" but rather "how to combine this splitting with reading from a file".

Comment: You're **not** creating a one-element list, `bigtweet` is just a string. There's nothing convoluted about it. IMHO, the sample code is already good enough.

Comment: @Błotosmętek: the file is an iterable. The solution there can be directly applied to the file object.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it is not the file that is to be chunked, but a **line** from this file.

Comment: @Błotosmętek: ah, that's the defining detail; I didn't go any further than `a whole file is read in using readlines()`.

Comment: At which point [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](//stackoverflow.com/q/312443) is the canonical; the OP has already applied that, there is nothing to add really. The code is indeed otherwise fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe just a minor change - it is not necessary to assign the list to a variable nor to iterate over indices, the list can be iterated over directly :

```
with open(tweet_datafile,'r') as smstweets:
    bigtweet = smstweets.readline().strip() 
for line in ( bigtweet[i:i+140] for i in range(0,len(bigtweet),140) ):
    twitter.update_status(status=line)
```

Comment: Then *at the very least* make that a generator expression, not a list comprehension. You do nothing else with that list.

Comment: @MartijnPieters generator expression will obviously be more memory-efficient, but also likely slower than list comprehension (at least that's my experience), so your suggestion might be valid or not, depending on what is the optimisation goal.

Comment: It's no slower *here*; the bytecode is almost the same but no list is built. As a result, it is in fact about 20% faster (for an input string of 10.000 random ascii letters, Python 3.6.2).

Comment: Thanks to both for your comments, and to Błotosmętek for the improvement. I had not understood properly that the comprehension can be iterated over directly (it is of course a list:))  but it's obvious to me now!   And yes I was not thinking clearly about the string/list distinction.  Being able to create variables 'on the fly' is great but it's not always obvious to beginners or non-professionals what one has created without thinking very explicitly.  thanks again.